# Git workflow with AWS CodeCommit

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

I don't have a lot of knowledge in Git and I recently started working with a new programmer on my team.

My workflow is basically as follows:

> I have a brach called **develop** to keep the development code.
>
> 1 - I create a new feature with : **git checkout develop** followed by **git checkout -b feature/newFeature**
>
> 2 - I commit the modifications of this new functionality: **git commit -m "New feature commit"**
>
> 3 - I merge this feature in the develop branch locally : **git checkout develop** followed by **git merge feature/newFeature**
>
> 5 - I push develop to the repository: **git push origin develop**
>
> 4 - I delete the branch: **git branch -d feature/newFeature**
>
> 6 - At this point I was able to test my application normally.

I worked a long time alone on this model and for me it worked perfectly. But now with someone else working on feature branches I would like to review these branch`s before merging with develop and there were doubts:

> I would like to ask this programmer to make a pull request in the codecommit whenever a feature branch ends. But I have doubts about how his workflow should be in git ... does he have to rebase before making the pull request? Should he delete this branch locally? Could someone show me how their workflow could look? Thank you!